# Will meta questions on the main site get moved here?

Tags: discussion, site-migration

There are still questions on the main money.se site tagged meta. Just search for [[meta], closed:0](https://money.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bmeta%5D+closed%3A0).
Should these questions be moved to meta.money.se? And are there other tags (such as [faq], [site-information]) that indicate a question's suitability on meta instead of the parent site?

Comment: I would guess that depends on their applicability.

Comment: The search now returns 0 questions. They've been removed from the main site.

Answer (score 1):

Lots of those were FAQs, so the FAQ page might need to represent them, but not the meta page.